# Can a Auto Clicker app be developed in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, touch, touch-event

Is this possible to create an auto clicker app like [Click Mate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inscode.autoclicker)? in flutter?
If yes then where should I start from? and if no then why not?
Auto clicker apps are basically some apps that stimulate fake touch on some fixed or user-defined areas.

Edit: The hardest part here for me is to perform a click even outside the app. It seems an impossible task and the worse thing is, I can't find any guide about this.

Comment: Hi, Bro I am also trying to make auto clicker app. Can you tell me how you able to click anywhere in the app???

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to perform a click inside or outside my app. I did not find any helpful tutorials yet.

Comment: Hi, did you get the clue on how to do it, i found how to click but click on a widget that you have a GlobalKey assaign to it, so did you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a win32 package to achieve this. It has a full functionality of windows API.
Its a bit tricky but possible. You need to write a bit of native code to achieve this. Here is an example of simple app that moves cursor to screen position of x = 1000, y = 1000.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:win32/win32.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyAPP());
}

class MyAPP extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('click'),
          onPressed: () {
            SetCursorPos(1000, 1000);
           
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain this more in detail and also share links for the tutorials if possible.

Comment: Added a small code snippet. For key press you can use SendInput() function.

Comment: So this is only for Windows, right?

Answer (score -3):

In simple, You can either use Future.delayed or Timer to do this.
Future.delayed example

```
Future _delayedFuture = Future.delayed(
  const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  () {
    // Call some function after a delay of 500ms
  },
);
```

Future.delayed cannot be cancelled, while timer can be.

Timer example:

```
Timer _timer = Timer(
  const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  () {
    // Call some function after a delay of 500ms
  },
);
```

If you want to cancel timer, use

> _timer.cancel()

You can also run timer periodically, by using

> Timer.periodic();

Comment: Thanks for your response but how I will be able to perform a touch or click outside my app?